# Plotting rectangle using minimum and maximum latitude and longitude in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Can we plot rectangle using minimum and maximum latitude and longitude in arcmap 10.2?

Here is a sample of the data i need to plot directly using latitude and longitude in polygon shapefile.

[image: Here is a sample of the data i need to plot directly using latitude and longitude in polygon shapefile.]

Answer (score 1):

If you had the coords in an excel file and each row was lat_min,lat_max,long_min,long_max you could do something like the following using Python.  Given that this is a simple example.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, re, xlrd
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

def dms_dd(dms_string):
    #parses a dms string in the following format 84°60'20" and return a decimal degree float number
    degrees,minutes,seconds,extra = re.split(r"[°'\"]+", dms_string)    
    decimal = 0.0
    if (int(degrees) >= 0):
        decimal = int(degrees) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/3600
    else:
        decimal = int(degrees) - float(minutes)/60 - float(seconds)/3600
    return decimal

def parseXLS_Data(xls_file):
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_file)
    sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    nrows = sheet.nrows
    ncols = sheet.ncols
    all_coords = []
    for row in range(nrows):
        if row == 0:
            pass
        else:
            x_min = dms_dd(sheet.row(row)[0].value)
            x_max = dms_dd(sheet.row(row)[1].value)
            y_min = dms_dd(sheet.row(row)[2].value)
            y_max = dms_dd(sheet.row(row)[3].value)
            coords =  [[x_min,y_min],[x_max,y_min],[x_max,y_max],[x_min,y_max]]
            all_coords.append(coords)
    return all_coords

def makepoly(coord_list, shp_file, SR=None):
    features = []
    #Convert a Python list of coordinates to an ArcPy polygon feature
    for polygon in coord_list:
        poly = arcpy.Array()
        for vertex in polygon:
            point = arcpy.Point(vertex[0],vertex[1])
            poly.append(point)
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(poly,SR)
        features.append(polygon)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, shp_file)


file_xls = "path\to\coords\file.xls"
shp_file = r"path\to\polygon.shp"
polygons = parseXLS_Data(file_xls)
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
p = makepoly(polygons, shp_file, SR=SR)
```

The excel file looks like this:

[image]